# DFT of image in Emgu 3.0+

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, opencv, emgucv, dft

How can I compute a DFT of an image with Emgu 3.0+ in visual basic?

I have some image I load in as a Mat with CvInvoke.Imread(), which I can display and alter, and I'd like to compute the forward DFT of this image, then display the magnitudes. How can I do this? I'm having trouble with inputting valid IInputArrays into CvInvoke.Dft(). My Emgu version is 3.1.0 at the moment.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
    Dim imgOrig As Mat
    imgOrig = CvInvoke.Imread(ofd.FileName, LoadImageType.AnyColor)

    EmguImageBox.Image = imgOrig

    Dim imgGrayscale As New Mat()
    CvInvoke.CvtColor(imgOrig, imgGrayscale, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray)

    EmguImageBox.Image = imgGrayscale

    Dim imgDFT As Mat
    imgDFT = New Mat(imgOrig.Rows, imgOrig.Cols, DepthType.Cv32F, 2)

    CvInvoke.Dft(imgGrayscale, imgDFT, DxtType.Forward, 0)

    EmguImageBox.Image = imgDFT
```

Comment: Can you include that code that you have already tried?

Comment: I've generally been trying to follow this guy's method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812950/how-do-i-compute-dft-and-its-reverse-with-emgu , but errors are appearing. I'll add in some code I've been trying.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already solved this, but here is some info that might put others with the same problem on the right path. I have myself tried to do the same in Emgu version 3.1.0, but found only examples using older versions of Emgu. Finally got something working, maybe you are able to implement the same in VB.

```
 #region Perform FFT
                //Get optimal DFT size
                int m = CvInvoke.GetOptimalDFTSize(originalImg.Height);
                int n = CvInvoke.GetOptimalDFTSize(originalImg.Width);

                //Resize image
                Mat resizedImg = new Mat();
                CvInvoke.CopyMakeBorder(originalImg, resizedImg, 0, m - originalImg.Height, 0, n - originalImg.Width, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BorderType.Default);

                //Create imaginary channel for original image    
                Mat imChannel = new Mat(resizedImg.Size, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, 1);
                imChannel.SetTo(new MCvScalar(0));
                //Add both real and imaginary channel to Mat vector
                Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfMat vectorMat = new Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfMat(new Mat[2] { resizedImg, imChannel });
                //Create 2 channel Mat from the vector
                Mat FFTimg = new Mat(resizedImg.Size, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, 2);
                CvInvoke.Merge(vectorMat, FFTimg);

                //Perform DFT
                CvInvoke.Dft(FFTimg, FFTimg, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DxtType.Forward, 0);

                //Split channels to separate Mat objects
                CvInvoke.Split(FFTimg, vectorMat);

                //Calculate magnitudes
                Mat fftMag = new Mat();
                CvInvoke.Pow(vectorMat[0], 2, vectorMat[0]);
                CvInvoke.Pow(vectorMat[1], 2, vectorMat[1]);
                CvInvoke.Add(vectorMat[0], vectorMat[1], fftMag);
                CvInvoke.Sqrt(fftMag, fftMag);

                //Swith quadrants 
                Mat q1 = new Mat(fftMag, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, (int)(fftMag.Height - fftMag.Height / 2), (int)(fftMag.Width / 4), fftMag.Height - (int)(fftMag.Height - fftMag.Height / 2)));
                Mat q2 = new Mat(fftMag, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, (int)(fftMag.Width / 4), (int)(fftMag.Height / 2)));

                Mat tmp = new Mat();
                q1.CopyTo(tmp);
                q2.CopyTo(q1);
                tmp.CopyTo(q2);
                #endregion
```